# Continuously loop colors on div using javascript on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, colors

I have a div on a page and I would like to **continuously cycle** through a set of **colors** using **javascript**.

I've seen a number of articles on Stack Overflow about continuous loops to show *information* using **arrays and javascript** yet I have had trouble trying to implement it into my own project.

My HTML:

```
<div id="box" style="background:grey;" onmouseenter="change()"></div>
```

and the closest JS solution I can find:

```
var change = function() {
    colors = ['#00b0e2', '#e3144e', '#15e39b'];
    count = -1;
    return function() {
        return colors[++count % colors.length];
    }
    document.getElementById('box').style.background = colors; // or should this be **colors[]**?
}
```

I understand what is happening up until the return function but then I am having trouble understanding how to inject the color into the html?

Any help or tips would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are really close, but are missing a couple of key things.

**Firstly**, when you say `onmouseover="change()"` that means that it will run `change()` every time the mouseover runs unlike using `addEventListener(change())` which would run the function returned by `change` as the event handler.

**Secondly** to change the element, all you need to do is get a handle on the element and set the background.

The code below does what I think you were trying to do but more simply. I hope it helps.

```js
// setup our colors and state once
colors = ['#00b0e2', '#e3144e', '#15e39b'];
count = -1;

var change = function(element) {
  element.style.background = colors[++count % colors.length]; 
}
```

```html
<!-- Pass in the element when creating the change listener -->
<div id="box" style="background:grey;" onmouseenter="change(this)">
  Give our box some contents so we can see it.
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

the basic concept behind the loop is that we have a `count` that tells us `colors[count]` is currently active.

When a `mouseover` happens, three things happen in the one line.

- `++count`: this adds `1` to `count`, but unlike `count++`, it does so before the value is used. Meaning that the first time a `mouseover` occurs, the value of `count` is `0`
- `count % colors.length`: This just lets us wrap around to the first color once it has hit the last color. The `%` (*modulus*) operator gives the remainder. `a % b` will return the remainder after dividing `a / b`. If `count = 0`, `count % 3` yields 0, but if `count = 4`, `count % 3` yields 1. You can read more about this and other Arithmetic operators on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())
- `element.style.background = colors[...]`: This sets the `background` css attribute to the color we selected in the last step.

so to put it all together, here is the `change` function broken out into 3 lines.

```
var change = function(element){
    count++; //increment count before using it.
    var our_color = count % colors.length; // wrap properly
    element.style.background = colors[our_color];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mobius. That's exactly how I wanted it to work. I appreciate your time in explaining it too.I'm still new to JS, so don't know what type of loop you used? (element.style.background = colors[++count % colors.length]; ) Can you tell me what it is so I can read up on it?